# window.open scrollbars not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a link that opens a popup window using `window.open()`. The problem is the scrollbars don't work in Chrome. They work in IE and Firefox, so I'm thinking it has something to do with Chromes new scroll bars. This is an example of the code I'm using:

**html:**

```
<a href="http://google.com">Click Me</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a').click(function() {
    window.open("http://google.com", "", "width=300,height=300,scrollbars=1");
});
```

I also set up a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/88GBR/

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you're right - until the new scroll bars are fixed, not sure of a way around it.  The wheel should still work though - this has been bugging me since the update.

Comment: I am using the latest ver of chrome and your scrollbars are working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

> scrollbars=yes|no|1|0 Whether or not to display scroll bars. *IE, Firefox & Opera only*

try to set css-prop explicitly `overflow: scroll;`, otherwise no chance I guess

Comment: it works for me in reverse, i.e. by trying to hide scrollbars, I had to add overflow: hidden; to the body tag of a dynamically created window

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m running on Windows Vista x32

Tried to post screenshot but I don't have required rep, tried to post this as a comment instead of an answer but hey... don't have that rep either :D

Comment: Yeah I thought I had the latest version, but apparently I didn't. I updated to 32.0.1700.102 and it works now. It's still pretty bad that the scroll bars don't work in the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

in this way should work, but i would try the window.open action in a 'div' and not in an 'anchor'

```
$("#divClick").click(function(){ 
window.open("https://www.google.com","some","toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=900px,height=500px");

}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it didn't work. I updated my Chrome to version 32.0.1700.102 and now it works fine. Still a weird bug though. I guess people with that version of chrome are out of luck. I'm not sure how you'd go about fixing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case..
call 3 function then working fine~!!

document.open --> document.writer --> document.close

e.g.

```js
var option = 'menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=600,width=800';
var win = window.open(null, null, option);
var div = domConstruct.create('div');

/// add content in div ...

win.document.open(); // must call...
win.document.write(div.innerHTML);
win.document.close(); // must cal...
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me, i find my crome was not supporting scrollbars=1 so i changed it as scrollbars=yes

```
var docprint = window.open('', '', 'scrollbars=yes,resizeable=yes,width=900, height=850'); 
    docprint.document.open(); 
    docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Page Setup<\/title>'); 
    docprint.document.write('<\/head><body onLoad="self.print()"><center>');          
    docprint.document.write(data); 
    docprint.document.write('<\/center><\/body><\/html>'); 
    docprint.document.close(); 
    docprint.focus();
```